# post params with groovy httpbuilder in mailgun

Tags: groovy, mailgun, httpbuilder

I am trying to invoke mailgun send message api. The following code works if I pass the params along with url -

```
String targetUrl = "https://api.mailgun.net/v2/my_domain_name/messages?from=fromAddress&to=toAddress&subject=sub&text=random+message"
```

But when I try to add these params in the body then it does not work. I keep getting bad request from mailgun.  -

```
String targetUrl = "https://api.mailgun.net/v2/my_domain_name/messages
body = [from:"fromAddress", to:"toAddress", subject:"sub", text:"random message"]
```

Here is the full code -

```
def sendEmail(String mailBody, String sub, String toIds) {
    String targetUrl = "https://api.mailgun.net/v2/my_domain_name/messages"
    def http = new HTTPBuilder(targetUrl)

    http.request( groovyx.net.http.Method.POST, groovyx.net.http.ContentType.JSON) {

        body = [from:"fromAddress", to:"toAddress", subject:"sub", text:"random message"]

        headers = ['Authorization':"Basic " + "api:my_api_key".bytes.encodeBase64().toString()]

        response.success = { resp, reader ->
            println "valid response: " + reader
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can't find docs but you're sending query params as body, that's not correct - use query params. As far as I remember it should be sent as `params` map, just change `body` to `params`.

Comment: @Opal Thats what I also thought at first. I tried params in place of body. But it seems httpbuilder does not have any property named params.

Comment: Try `uri.query = <map with params>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is not working because you are telling `HTTPBuilder` that the request's parameters are encoded in `JSON`

> `http.request(Method.POST, ContentType.JSON)`

so that you are encoding your parameters in request body in JSON, while [mailgun API](https://documentation.mailgun.com/quickstart-sending.html#send-via-api) expects them with `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

> ```
> curl -s --user 'api:YOUR_API_KEY' \
>     https://api.mailgun.net/v2/YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME/messages \
>     -F from='Excited User <mailgun@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME>' \
>     -F to=YOU@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME \
>     -F to=bar@example.com \
>     -F subject='Hello' \
>     -F text='Testing some Mailgun awesomness!'
> ```

You can see it using as `targetURL` http://echo.httpkit.com, that returns the HTTP request in JSON format.

Doing that, it yields:

```
{
    "body": "\"from\":\"fromAddress\",\"to\":\"toAddress\",\"subject\":\"sub\",\"text\":\"random message\"}",
"docs": "http://httpkit.com/echo",
[...]
```

So you have to use `ContentType.URLENC` instead of `ContentType.JSON` (and optionally use `Accept` header for `application/json` type):

```
import groovy.json.*

import groovyx.net.*
import groovyx.net.http.*

import static groovy.json.JsonOutput.*

import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.*
import static groovyx.net.http.Method.*

String targetUrl = 'http://echo.httpkit.com'
def http = new HTTPBuilder(targetUrl)

http.request(POST) {
    uri.path = '/'
    requestContentType = URLENC

    body = [from: 'fromAddress', to: 'toAddress', subject: 'sub', text: 'random message']

    headers.'Authorization' = "Basic " + "api:my_api_key".bytes.encodeBase64().toString()
    headers.'Accept' = 'application/json'

    response.success = { resp, json ->
        println prettyPrint(toJson(json))
    }
}
```

That yields this "echo" response (i.e., sent a POST request with urlencoded parameters):

```
{
    "body": "from=fromAddress&to=toAddress&subject=sub&text=random+message",
    "docs": "http://httpkit.com/echo",
    "headers": {
        "accept": "application/json",
        "authorization": "Basic YXBpOm15X2FwaV9rZXk=",
        "content-length": "61",
        "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "host": "echo.httpkit.com",
        "x-forwarded-for": "195.235.15.200"
    },
    "ip": "127.0.0.1",
    "method": "POST",
    "path": {
        "name": "/",
        "params": {

        },
        "query": ""
    },
    "powered-by": "http://httpkit.com",
    "uri": "/"
}
```